# casting base class to derived class via reflection

Tags: java, reflection, downcast

Hi I have to construct an object from an object. Since the base class has more than 50 fields i dont want to do things like

```
//obj1 is an instance of BaseClass
DerivedClass obj2 = new DerivedClass();
obj2.setField1(obj1.getField1());
obj2.setField2(obj1.getField2())
.... so on
```

As you see from the title i want to downcast my object but java does not allow this. Is there a utility library or smth that provides a method like

```
Object convert(BaseClass obj1, DerivedClass obj2)
```

Comment: Why would you need a cast? The above code, not using reflection, doesn't make any cast. So the same code using reflection shouldn't do any cast either. That said, that's really not a good reason to use reflection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Apache [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) to do this. Using its `BeanUtils` class you have access to a lot of utility methods for populating JavaBeans properties via reflection.

To copy all the common/inherited properties from a base class object to a derived class object you can use its static `copyProperties()` method as

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(baseClassObj, derivedClassObj);
```

From the [BeanUtils.copyProperties()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) docs

> Copy property values from the origin bean to the destination bean for all cases where the property names are the same.

If you don't want to use a third-party library, your next best option would be to provide a utility method on the derived class that initializes itself with all the properties of an instance of its parent class.

```
public void initFromParent(BaseClass obj) {
    this.propOne = obj.getPropOne();
    // ... and so on
}
```

Comment: _You definitely answered his question_, but so that everyone coming later understands, building an object via a bean piecemeal should be a last-resort kind of thing -- using a constructor or composition would be far safer as you could then preserve class contracts/invariants.

Comment: Yeah, constructor makes sense too but then you're restricting the copy to one time initialization. With a method you can copy the state anytime. It would depend on case to case basis. And I won't suggest composition as OP's already using inheritance and we don't know enough about the program entities to proclaim which one would fit better.

Comment: A single argument method with the object to clone would be superior to copying properties, as the object is in an inconsistent state until you call all setters. The solution to a long copy method is not to use beans+reflection, but rather to break the object down into manageable parts. Again, I understand that this isn't your idea.

Comment: Yes, if the object is shared then a composition with the passed in parent object simply cloned and set as a member is definitely a better idea. I see where you coming from now. In a multi-threaded environment I would have to synchronize while the properties are being copied.

Answer (score 0):

You can downcast if the cast is valid:

```
BaseClass instance = new DerivedClass();
if(DerivedClass.class.isAssignableFrom(instance.getClass()) {
    DerivedClass dc = DerivedClass.class.cast(instance);
}
```

But normally one would implement a constructor with the same arguments and call `super()`.

Or even better, use composition, where instead of inheritance you have DerivedClass hold an instance of BaseClass and delegate calls for the fields to that object.